# best approach to set bottomNavigation status from the current Active Link according to the entered path (Reach Router - Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, reach-router

I am using `react-router` and `material-ui`. I have a BottomNavigation and BottomNavigationAction (MaterialUI) (with Link component from Reach Roouter ).

```
import { Link } from "@reach/router"

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
myButtomNavigation: {
  color: '#000',
  '&$selected': {
    paddingTop: '16px',
  },
},
selected: {
},
}));


export default function Navigation(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('INIT');
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return(
      <BottomNavigation value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
      <BottomNavigationAction showLabel={false} value="INIT" icon={<HomeOutlinedIcon />}  component={Link} to="/" classes={{root: classes.myButtomNavigation, selected: classes.selected}} />
      <BottomNavigationAction showLabel={false} value="ANIMALS" icon={<PetsOutlinedIcon />} component={Link} to="/animals" classes={{root: classes.myButtomNavigation, selected: classes.selected}}/>
      <BottomNavigationAction showLabel={false} value="ROUTINE" icon={<NotificationsOutlinedIcon />} component={Link} to="/activities" classes={{root: classes.myButtomNavigation, selected: classes.selected}} />
      <BottomNavigationAction showLabel={false} value="SETTINGS" icon={<SettingsOutlinedIcon />} component={Link} to="/configuration" classes={{root: classes.myButtomNavigation, selected: classes.selected}} />
    </BottomNavigation>
  );
}
```

I have a problem to know how to get the current active Link and set it to the value of the BottomNavigation when someone entered a different url than the root path from the browser.
When i enter with the root path (localhost:3000/): all is work (because i set value to root path).
When i enter with other path, like localhost:3000/animals i need to set the correct value so the right icon show active.

Reach Router gives a possiblity in Link component: passing a function to getProps that you can return a style for the current active link but the style affect anchor element and i need to affect an other object (https://reach.tech/router/example/active-links).

How can i set the value of bottomNavigation according to the current active link when someone entered path from browser (and is not the rootpath)??

Answer (score 0):

In react-router-dom I am using  NavLink with property (activeClassName="current") instead of Link, maybe there is something similar in Reach Router.

Comment: it's not about that. It's about how to get the active Link value when someone entered a different path than a root path from the browser. Otherwise, it's ok.

Comment: Not sure if you you can use value, you can pass function handleChange as props to every page and use {Match} where you can grab url and pass it to your state.

Comment: i am using Location from Reach Router to pass a location to others component.
https://dev.to/mikewheaton/navigating-with-ant-design-and-reach-router-382a
And i set the defauIt value to location.pathname. It works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the current page link - eg "/configuration/..."

> const urlPage = window.location.pathname.substring(1).split("/")[0];

- urlPage = "configuration"

2. Create an array of the links you need

> const urlArrays = ["home", "link", "animals", "configuration"];

- and now simply use

> `<BottomNavigation showLabels value={urlArrays.indexOf(urlPage)}>`